# SQL LITE : one row constraint

Tags: sqlite

I am creating a table in SQLite Database which will only store a single data, else if data exists in the table, it should be deleted before inserting a new data.

This is the syntax i used to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE my_login_info (
    id       BOOLEAN PRIMARY KEY
                     DEFAULT True
                     CONSTRAINT one_row_only CHECK (id) 
                     NOT NULL,
    username STRING,
    password STRING
);
```

however when i am trying to insert the data to the table while the table is empty, it gave an error.

```
Error while committing new row: CHECK constraint failed: one_row_only
```

Any idea what is the caused the problem?

Comment: MySQL or SQLite? Please remove unrelated databases tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ensure SQLite table only has one row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104101/ensure-sqlite-table-only-has-one-row)

Comment: You probably don't need SQLite if you only intend to store a single value. If you want to update, just don't use INSERT. Use UPDATE

Comment: You can use `INSERT OR REPLACE` eg `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO my_login_info (id,username,HashField_Not_Password)
 (true,someuser,SOME_HASH_NOT_CLEARTEXT_PASSWORD)`

Comment: And make sure you *don't* store passwords in the database, only hashes.

Comment: @StefanoZanini not a duplicate - the linked question is more complex and the solution is more complex than what is needed in this case

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please make as answer and i will accept it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INSERT OR REPLACE` to insert a new record or update the existing one that matches the key field, eg:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO my_login_info (id,username,hash) 
VALUES (true,someuser,somehash)
```

Just make sure you *don't* store the password as cleartext. Only store a strong hash. If you don't need the hash for authentication, you could get away with storing a short hash, ie only part of the full hash.

That's what git does for example, when it displays a short hash for each file version instead of the full hash